# Easyredmine's Gantt chart bars aren't in line with the task list items

Tags: redmine, gantt

This question goes to the Easyredmine users out there.

As you can see in the cropped out section down there, we can't get a proper seamless transition from the task list to the chart bars on the Gantt charts. We tried 4 different browsers, tried to zoom in and out, added and subtracted columns from the task lists, changed the grouping options without success.

I've already submitted a ticket to Easyredmine but would like to hear from you, too. Did anyone of you bump into this problem and if yes could you solve it?

[image: Easyredmine Gantt Chart detail]

Comment: This is now resolved?

Comment: Yes. Easyredmine's latest update has solved this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easyredmine's latest update has solved this issue.